# Email Experience Manager Module Installation Issue

Tags: exm, installation

I have `Sitecore 8.2 update 5` and am trying to install `Email Experience Manager 3.5 rev. 170810 (Initial Release)`

From the downloaded & extracted zip, I have uploaded - `Email Experience Manager 3.5.0 rev. 170810.zip`

The installation ran for hours and I had to close it. There were also no errors logged.

But in the launch pad, I see the EXM icon and when clicked on it, it throws the error:

```
    The partial view '/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ECM/EmailCampaign.Controls/AccountInformationExt/AccountInformationExt.cshtml' 
    was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. 
    The following locations were searched:
    /sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ECM/EmailCampaign.Controls/AccountInformationExt/AccountInformationExt.cshtml
```

I extracted the package to find the file, but it wasn't there. To my surprise, it wasn't there in any folder of package.zip.

[image]

Is this a bug.

Or is there any other way to install EXM.

**StackTrace:**

> [InvalidOperationException: The partial view
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ECM/EmailCampaign.Controls/AccountInformationExt/AccountInformationExt.cshtml'
>   was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The
>   following locations were searched:
>   /sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ECM/EmailCampaign.Controls/AccountInformationExt/AccountInformationExt.cshtml]
>   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.FindPartialView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   String partialViewName, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
>   +416    System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter
>   writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) +225
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +136    Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +315
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ECM/EmailCampaign.Controls/AccountInformationExt/AccountInformationExt.cshtml'
>   (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc'). ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +787 
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +73    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String
>   placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +183
>   (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String
>   placeholderName) +258
>   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_Layouts_Renderings_Structures_Substructures_GlobalHeader_cshtml.Execute()
>   +622    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252    System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +136    Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +315
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component
>   Library/Layouts/Renderings/Structures/Substructures/GlobalHeader.cshtml'
>   (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc'). ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +787 
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +73    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String
>   placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +183
>   (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String
>   placeholderName) +258
>   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Business_Component_Library_Layouts_Renderings_Structures_Page_Structures_Application_Dashboard_cshtml.Execute()
>   +273    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252    System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +136    Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +315
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Business Component
>   Library/Layouts/Renderings/Structures/Page
>   Structures/Application/Dashboard.cshtml' (model:
>   'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc'). ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +787 
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +73    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String
>   placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +183
>   (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String
>   placeholderName) +258
>   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml.Execute()
>   +2015    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252    System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +136    Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +315
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-Layout.cshtml'
>   (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc'). ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +787 
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +73    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +331
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +375    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +88
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +776
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +776
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36

Comment: Too old to answer. However for anyone landing in this post: check whether your EXM config files are in place.
I faced the same and the problem was my config files were missing. I just put it back and all good.

Comment: Check if this config having this setting in the web.config file - <add key="exmEnabled:define" value="yes" />

Answer (score 3):

The .cshtml files are now embedded in the `Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Ui` assembly using Razor Generator.

If you look deeper into the stacktrace, you might find Glass Mapper. If so, this is a known issue and you'll need to look into upgrading Glass.

Slightly related: http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Documentation/CompileRazorViewSupport

Comment: We are not using Glass for our project

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace in your question?  Also it's not a good sign that you had to stop the installation, so the config file which registers the assembly with embedded razor files is probably missing: App_Config\Include\EmailExperience\Sitecore.EmailExperience.UI.config

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're missing DLL's to be quite honest.  The fact it took that long to install the package makes me think Sitecore coughed up a hairball when installing the DLL's, worker pool recycled, and the installed crapped out leaving out important DLL's.  That's my working theory.

Check your bin folder and make sure you have the following DLL's present.

[image: EXM DLL's]